# How to create, insert, and update collections with meteor vlasky:mysql package?

Tags: mysql, database, meteor

I want to know how to CREATE MySql collections on Meteor, INSERT and UPDATE these collections with the meteor vlasky:mysql package. I know how to publish data to clients with the package and how to subscribe to (SELECT queries) but I want my application to be 100% MySQL. Can anyone help me ? I search on the net but don't have documentation about it.

Comment: Can't you just use any mysql package for node.js to insert into your database? It doesn't have to be the same package you are using for publishing from it.

Comment: Ok I got it, can you suggest me one package in particular ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the README of [the package](https://github.com/vlasky/meteor-mysql/) you are referring to states:

> For operations other than SELECT, like UPDATE and INSERT, an active [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) connection (or pool) is exposed via the LiveMysql.db (or LiveMysql.pool) property.

So this should work:

```js
var post  = {id: 1, title: 'Hello MySQL'};
var query = LiveMysql.db.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // Neat!
});
console.log(query.sql); // INSERT INTO posts SET `id` = 1, `title` = 'Hello MySQL'
```

Comment: Ok I will try this.